# Spring boot 2.2.0 response throws 502 error upstream sent too big header in k8s nginx

Tags: spring-boot, nginx, kubernetes, nginx-reverse-proxy

We recently upgraded from Spring boot 2.1.2 Release to Spring boot 2.2.0 Release and started having an issue  "502 error upstream sent too big header" from upstream service.
Here is the request flow:

Browser --> K8s nginx (1.15.0) --> api-gateway(Zuul with Spring Boot 2.2) --> Backend service.

Backend response is a 302 redirect with location that has URL and some app data.

Only thing that is changed here is Spring boot upgrade in api-gateway and backend services.

I verified responses ( headers and data) from the api-gateway to the nginx k8s server and responses are same between Spring boot versions.

Here is the error in nginx logs:
2021/09/29 17:16:01 [error] 44#44: *68665904 **upstream sent too big header while reading response header from upstream**, client: 10.221.200.342, server:gateway.x.y.io, request: "POST /r/l HTTP/2.0", upstream: "http://10.221.200.342:8080/x/y", host: "gateway.x.y.io"

Upgraded packages:

Old: Spring boot 2.1.3 Release, org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:Greenwich.RELEASE and Standard spring boot rest dependencies.

New: Spring boot 2.2.0 Release, org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:Hoxton.RELEASE and Standard spring boot rest dependencies

Appreciate suggestions on how to debug the root cause or resolve this issue other than increasing proxy_buffer limits in nginx .

--10/6 update

More updates: Here are logs from nginx access logs for successful response.
Reduced location length in response so it succeeds in Spring 2.2.

Spring Boot 2.2.0 - 10.244.2.128 - [10.244.2.128] - - [06/Oct/2021:01:35:56 +0000] "POST /x/y HTTP/2.0" 302 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/94.0.4606.54 Safari/537.36" 7580 3.354 [x-y-z-80] 10.244.1.48:8080 0 **3.290** 302 7d9cfce0f1ae70b1ec007a9474f60b9e

Spring Boot 2.1.2 - 10.244.2.128 - [10.244.2.128] - - [06/Oct/2021:13:16:34 +0000] "POST /x/y HTTP/2.0" 302 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/94.0.4606.54 Safari/537.36" 7580 3.091 [z-x-y-80] 10.244.1.97:8080 0 **3.026** 302 62f2348644328eedacad8ccc9b195415.

Thing to notice: texts in bold are the response length ($upstream_response_length nginx) and are different.

Comment: Are you sure you don't want to set [`http2-max-header-size:`](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/configmap/#http2-max-header-size) in the nginx `ConfigMap`?

Comment: Yes, we don't want to set this value.  This issue happened in prod when we upgraded to 2.2. Nginx has a limit of 4k which is the same between spring versions. We made a fix in application by reducing response length (302 redirect location). I am doing RCA and want to know what has changed in 2.2 or what is it sending that causes error in nginx.

Comment: Ok, competing theory: was the old version using HTTP/1.1 and the new one HTTP/2?

Comment: Update: it is http2.0 in both cases:. This is the nginx log for request in spring 2.1.2 : 10.244.0.129 - [10.244.0.129] - - [06/Oct/2021:00:50:10 +0000] "POST /sx/mP HTTP/2.0" 302 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/94.0.4606.54 Safari/537.36" 7580 6.210 [x-y-gateway-80] 10.244.1.40:8080 0 6.208 302 7b9a8f14dba0c87a8a61d3f0d6df24fa
1

Comment: Updated comment in the main query due to length limit.

Comment: Did you try to enable the logs to log the headers and body to see what's coming on nginx? It is a good thing to figure out why the requests are bigger now.